# Dell power adapter specification types

Tags: laptop, charger

In the specifications for the Alienware 17r4 on the [dell support site](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/alienware-17-laptop/alienware-17-r4-setupandspecifications/power-adapter?guid=guid-060d8d2d-5d9c-431f-9328-1eac085d46cc&lang=en-us) there are three listed "types", 180w, 240w and 330w. I am unsure what "type" means here. Does it mean that any of these options will work with this laptop? Or that these are different options depending on the exact build of this laptop? Or something else I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They list 2 different batteries, several video options & several storage options - which PSU you need depends on all these factors. It's not 'one laptop' it's a whole family hiding behind one product designation.

They're all the same input & output voltage, which is the important bit to not get wrong. The only difference is the Amperage [& Wattage, as those values are tied together W = V*A]. You can't have "too many amps" because in effect, amps are pulled by the device not pushed by the charger.

Perhaps if you order one of these laptops from them, the system will offer you the most suitable as part of the specifications you choose - but if in doubt just get the biggest.
All it will hurt is your wallet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the proper voltage, the type here refers to the amount of power being supplied from 180 watts (say 9 amps at 20 volts) up to 330 or almost twice as much power.

You might need the most powerful adapter for heavy duty video and games.

Also the adapter Type may be for more than one laptop. Manufacturers use the same adapters for multiple computers.

You could probably use the smaller adapter for common user or business activities.

If you wish to get just one adapter, get the 330 watt adapter. That will work fine.

Power is pulled, not pushed, so there is no issue having the larger adapter except size

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was specifically wondering why dell lists multiple types on their website.

Comment: They list 2 different batteries, several video options & several storage options - which PSU you need depends on all these factors. It's not 'one laptop' it's a whole family hiding behind one product designation. You can't go wrong with getting the 'biggest'. All it will hurt is your wallet ;)

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin That was one of my suspicions. If you make this an answer I'll happily accept it.